# Should users be allowed to entered a password with a space at the beginning or end?

Tags: passwords

Should users be able to enter a password such as " 12345" or "12345 " – a space at the beginning or end? Or would you trim the password to remove the leading or trailing spaces because it may just a typing error.

Comment: [Google](https://accounts.google.com/signup) and [Microsoft](https://signup.live.com/signup) appear to be trimming passwords so the idea doesn't seem far-fetched.

Comment: 10 years late... but this answer offers good trade-off...  https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/8020/67374 (basically, don't trim the password, but on login, if the password fails, silently try again with a trimmed password). Win-win situation.

Comment: Never ever change the typed password!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yes, they should.

- It annoys me to no end when people decide how my password should behave especially when it's nonsensical.  I would like more than 8 characters please.
- You should be hashing the password, so maximum character lengths and spaces at the end don't matter.

No, you should not trim it.

- You require a user to enter the password twice (when creating it) to eliminate typing errors.  Therefore a space doesn't matter.

Comment: The number of banking and credit card sites that won't let me set my password to space, $, * i.e. non alpha characters beggars belief.

Comment: @Bryan - why should space at the front of a password be treated any differently from say underscore or $. It's a typeable character in the plain old ascii range and hardly going to cause any kind of unicode type wierdness. I think if you can type it it should be acceptable.

Comment: ...is the opinion I humbly offer. :)

Comment: why? I guess I haven't thought very deeply about it. My gut reaction is that it would confuse most people, or at least those who are lousy typists and also write their passwords on a piece of paper. I don't think trimming is the best policy, but it may be the more real-world-practical.

Comment: I think it's time we stopped worrying so much about the small few people that are too dumb to accidentally put a space before their password, twice, and write it down (bad), and then forget it. They earned it, imo.

Comment: I disagree to this. When typing their password for logging in, someone might copy and paste it, which adds an extra whitespace here or there. If you don't trim this in your login processing code, they won't be able to login even though to them the password is exactly the same. Especially if your audience is non-technical. So no, spaces shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: @Click that's a very good point.  I think it's one of those tricky situations.  If I had unlimited resources I would detect a paste event versus a type event, and display a message that there was a space at the end of a paste.

Comment: yes allow spaces (the more possible characters the longer it will take to brute), don't put max limit on password length only min, you should hash the password and choose something stronger than md5 or sha (SHA-512, bcrypt is good, there are others), salt using good entropy, if you are on a linux server. I prefer urandom, as random doesn't wait for the entropy pool to have enough entropy. If the entropy pool is depleted the salt will not be truly random. On the other had urandom does wait. Of course salting is to protect from rainbow attacks after your database has been compromised.

Comment: You should not be able to paste into the a password confirmation field anyway. On logins yes why not, but when you create an account you should deactivate pasting.

Comment: @TeeJaay That's a horrible idea.  Loads of people generate something like a 15 character password - you can't expect people to slowly type those out.

Comment: @Tom you are right, thought about it and i must agree I don't know what I had to drink that day.

Comment: @John you've got it wrong. `urandom` is the unblocking/unlimited one that doesn't wait for fresh entropy. [citation 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=/dev/random) [citation 2](http://stupefydeveloper.blogspot.com/2007/12/random-vs-urandom.html) [citation 3](http://www.onkarjoshi.com/blog/191/device-dev-random-vs-urandom/)

Comment: @ClickUpvote They would have to make the mistake twice. If that happens, they can use the reset password option.

Comment: Just tried at https://accounts.google.com/signup.  I can't create an account where the trimmed password length is below 8.  After creation though, I can log in even when there's an arbitrary number of spaces around my password.  (The same goes with other Unicode whitespaces such as U+3000.)

Comment: @ClickUpvote Users too non-technical and inattentive to consider or notice things like extra whitespace in a password copy-paste should be (and increasingly *are*) taught to use password managers (whether standalone ones or those built into things like web browsers), which obviates that problem while having all sorts of other benefits.

Comment: @ClickUpvote And quite frankly, causing a missed whitespace in a password copy-paste enough times for it to be a problem, and having a bad enough reaction to it for it to be a problem, requires a combined level of inattention, negligence of security, lack of creative thinking, irrationally conclusive blame placement, and unhealthy coping with things not working how we want - not just in the moment but *habitually* - that a genuine argument can be made that catering to it has roughly the ethical complexities of catering to a drug habit like alcoholism.

Answer (score 43):

Let me tell you a story.

I needed to create an account on an ecommerce site, so I ran my random password generator to make an 8 character upper/lower/number/punctuation password, pasted it in twice to confirm it, finished registering with all of my personal information, and saved the random password in a local PGP-encrypted file for later use.

Later on I tried logging in, but pasting the password again didn't work.  After a bit of testing, I was horrified to find that the site had stripped out all punctuation marks from the original password, in some misguided attempt at sanitization, reducing my password to three easily brute forceable letters.

DON'T trim or sanitize users' passwords.

Comment: Good story, not quite sure it's completely related, but good for people to know/see.

Comment: I consider it related - he's talking about altering the user's password, so that password attempts that will be accepted are different than (and possibly easier than) what the user may intend.

Comment: Seems directly related to me.

Comment: Okay, "completely related" meaning that it isn't about a password, but instead about password validation in general, which is what the question has ended up being about. Still +1 for a great answer.

Comment: Care the share the name of that site? Seems like people really need to be warned.

Comment: Sorry, but this was over ten years ago, and I don't remember the site's name; it was some small music CD shop, I think.

Comment: @DarrylHein Right, it's not *completely* related - it's just *partially* related because it is an example of one failure mode that becomes possible once "let's modify the user's input password" thinking enters the mix. It does require other things to go wrong too (password setting and password checking on login code paths being different instead of reusing the same logic properly) but it **becomes a new possible problem to watch out for** once a project decides to modify the users' passwords on input.

Comment: I agree 100%. Except in the case of leading and trailing WS, which is just an accident waiting to happen... :)

Answer (score 20):

Never "clean up" a password simply to account for "typing mistakes".  This will confuse users and in some cases make it impossible for them to login.  In fact, don't ever change a password behind a user's back...always warn them that a password is invalid and let them try a new one.

A good example that I recently ran into was with a 3Com switch.  The web interface allowed me to change the admin password, but didn't warn me that the password was limited to eight characters.  I entered a password that was longer than eight characters.  When I tried to login after the change, it simply rejected my password.  If I only used the first eight characters, however, I was able to login (trial and error on my part, not fun).

Passwords these days don't look the way they used to.  For instance, my passwords often look like this:

```
Man, this program is really ticking me off!
```

Comment: That reminds me of a bad experience i've had with Windows passwords now on several occasions. I'll build a machine, configure the admin password, and then join it to the domain. The domain imposes password complexity rules that my password doesn't match. Now i can't log in to the admin account. Bah.

Comment: Back in the dark ages, I had this problem with my AIM account which was an AOL account.  Through AOL, I could use my full password, but apparently it just truncated to 8 chars behind the scenes every time, as when I started using stand-alone AIM, I couldn't login until I tried only 8 chars.

Answer (score 8):

You should validate the password with a confirmation field anyway.  If they make the typo twice - then you hopefully have a forgot password or a reset feature in place.

The space shouldn't matter as you shouldn't be storing it in plain text.

Answer (score 7):

The moment you make such a decision is the moment you start walking down the path of micro-management (over your users in this case).

Does a password containing a space break your system? Or is it a security risk? Then don't worry. Let your users deal with their own errors, even if that means they have to get frustrated. Their typo should never be your problem.

Comment: You should micromanage and *measure* your user experience.  Spin the dials, pull the levers and see what sticks! "Let your users deal with their own errors, even if that means they have to get frustrated" this attitude lacks empathy and not a path I would recommend.

Comment: @jms: So you enjoyed using the paperclip in Office, I presume?

Answer (score 6):

Space is a regular password character, and you shouldn't remove it.

Since you probably hash the password before storing it in the database, the space will be treated as any other character.

Answer (score 5):

I'm voting for: **No**, they shouldn't:

There's a big benefit for **not allowing** users to use spaces at the beginning and end of passwords and that's simply that it eliminates the problem which often arises when a user copies and pastes their password (e.g. from an email) and it includes white space which isn't part of the password.

The user then gets frustrated, thinks the system is broken and contacts support. A developer is promptly pulled onto the project to check the "buggy" login process only to spend a day pulling out his/her hair until he/she realises the problem.

I think enforcing this policy when creating a password solves more problems than it creates.

Comment: You should use a double input for that case, because a trailing or leading space is still valid and for the edge case, where a mistake is made twice, you can reset the password.

A password should never be seen after the very first entry, so it pretty much doesn't matter what chars are used.

Comment: The annoyance I've seen happen a number of times before is when a user has their password stored in a text file or an email or whatever. They then copy and paste this to login (not for signing up). So, sadly the double input isn't applicable in this case. Maybe it's an edge case and I've been unlucky?!

Comment: No, I don't think you have been unlucky, I think you're dealing with normal users (nobody who knows anything ever sends a password through email)

Thats fine for login, but when creating a password, you should prevent copy & paste.

Comment: @BrillPappin - I cannot think of a case, where a double input would solve the problem. Either they copy paste the password from somewhere, then they do it twice, or they enter it by hand and hardly make such a mistake. On the other side, it is my opinion that the strongness of a password should not depend on leading spaces/tabs. A password generator will never create such passwords, and the worst case is that you loose the strength of 1 character of the password (if the minimum length is checked after trimming i cannot see any problems).

Comment: @Lee - You still need to allow spaces as they are valid chars. The point is not to force the user to make a weaker password, or to modify the password without them knowing. It would be far better to give them an error asking them to remove leading or trailing spaces than to trim them.

Comment: @BrillPappin - Sorry, you're missing my point. I don't think you should modify the password when creating it. Like you say, you could just explain that leading/trailing spaces are not allowed when creating the password (it's just part of the site password policy). The trim would be performed when logging in to avoid the white space issue. Although you could argue that you're making the password less secure - I think it's negligible and the pros outweigh the cons.

Comment: @Lee I'm actually not missing your point, I know well that users do all kinds of filly things with their input, but leading and trailing spaces are not really unusable, they are simply additional characters.
The problem is that users copy and paste in the first place, and you can design a system that discourages that from the beginning.
There is no situation where it's a good idea to have a password written down, not in a notepad or an email (password transfer through email is one of the dumbest things a developer does to compromise their own security).

Comment: @Lee also, there is no such thing as "negligible" in security. That tiny negligible hole is all thats need for a hacker to make a big hole that you can never close. So, instead of trimming when they login, simply show them an error and ask them to remove the leading or trailing whitespace. You do that for creation, so why not authentication?

Answer (score 3):

It is fine for the password to contain it as already mentioned however I would add that when generating new random passwords (say for a sensible reset lost password system) you should avoid generating ones containing such tricky characters.

If the password is sufficiently long and random then this will make up for the restriction of a few tricky characters will make the end user's life considerably easier...

Comment: I generally avoid generating password where possibly, but instead have the user click a link to enter a password if they forget the existing one. One when the admin creates the account is a password generated automatically.

Comment: @DarrylHein How is sending a link any better than sending a password the user *has to change immediately after logging in to use it*?  If a bad actor intercepts the email with the link it will have exactly the same effect as if they got the one-time password.  I don't see how adding complexity to the system to handle password reset links adds to security - if anything, it *lowers* overall system security because there are more places that can break.

Comment: @FKEinternet I agree that it's not 100% better than sending the password, but you can do 2 things to help: (1) only allow the link to be used once and (2) put a time limit on how long the link works. This will at least prevent someone from finding the user's password in their email at a later date. If using their email for verification and someone has access to their email account, I think you're hooped no matter what. I've seen many links and temporary passwords never changed.

Answer (score 3):

I've been to a conference more than once where someone logged in to their account for a demo after the computer display was already up on the big screen, didn't change focus to the password field correctly, and thus their password was revealed to the entire audience.

Anyone who might have to enter credentials in front of others should consider keeping a trailing space or three in their password, just in case.  And when building authentication systems, you should *never* trim those spaces.

Comment: Hmm... How long d'ya think it'd take you to guess my password using trial-and-error, if you knew EVERYTHING about it, except for how many spaces i'd tacked on to the end. Including how long it takes me to type it... 

Hope the guy in your story changed his password after the demo!

Comment: No idea: I didn't know the presenters.  From the standpoint of the hacker, if I didn't know they had appended spaces I would likely assume it had changed.  From the standpoint of the presenter I would be hoping it bought me enough time to get through the presentation before changing it, even if the hacker is sitting in the audience with wifi.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's bad juju to store the password as text, there's no need to trim() the password since it'll immediately be hashed.

...
on a similar note, am I correct in believing that passwords shouldn't need to be regex validated to for sql injection since they'll be hashed and not inserted as plain text in the database?

Comment: I think you'd be correct on the later, except when you using MD5() or something similar directly within within SQL.

Comment: No input should be regex-validated at all. Just escape all problematic letters.

Comment: @Darryl, Thanks to Jeff's blog, I'm going with SHA256.

Answer (score 2):

I don't care. So long as whatever you do to the password when it is being set is also done to it when being entered later on. Trim, truncate, change case, salt, hash, whatever - just do it consistently.

Presumably you aren't storing the actual password anyway, so...

Comment: Good point...checking code...

Comment: Word.  Users are always cutting and pasting text and that last space gets them every time. Trim it, be consistent and don't bother me with it.

Comment: Except that you are potentially decreasing the complexity of the password without warning the user.  These days people tend to think about things like that.

Comment: @Boden: if you care about strong passwords (and you should) then enforce rules that specify sufficient characters and length needed to make a strong password. If you think it'll make things more usable, then trim. They're not mutually exclusive, so long as you are consistent.

Comment: ***NO!!!*** Do ***not*** change a user's password *entry* - use the *entry* as-is.  Whatever post-processing you do before storing a representation of it in the database - e.g., hashing as a good example - do *that* consistently - but use the *entry* **exactly** as the user entered it.  Anything else you do is going to just result in trouble - reread the stories told above by **@Josh Kelly** and **Boden** again, and if you still don't get it, reread them until you do!