# Interactive input that doesn't appear on the in the window in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that needs to ask the user a yes or no question at the end. Going based off the example .exe my teacher provided us, the line is supposed to print out "Would you like to print an Amortization Table(Y/N)?Y" and it looks for one keystroke from the user. The Y is printed out following the question like I typed, as it is supposed to represent the default choice so if the user presses `[y]`, `[shift + y]`, or `[enter]` it goes to the function that does the amortization table and if the user presses anything else it goes to the next line When it gets the input from the user it processes the keystroke instantly as it is pressed (it does not need `[enter]` to process the input) without letting the keystroke appear on the command prompt. I have tried all the functions I can think of to do this (getc, getchar, getche) but everything I have tried ends up printing the user's input. Does anyone know what function he used or what trick he is doing to keep the keystroke from appearing in the command prompt? Thanks for your help in advance, I am obviously new to programming.

Comment: This is probably platform specific, it would be good to know what operating system you are using.

Comment: @kotlinski he said example .exe so probably windows...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable echo in windows console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217908/how-to-disable-echo-in-windows-console)

Answer (score 0):

For the Windows platform, use the `_getch()` function from `<conio.h>` to read a keypress without buffering or echo.

Read the [function description on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)