# how do I remove the scanned number from the terminal so that I can't see it?

Tags: c

I am trying to create a minigame to play with my friends, where someone puts a number, and then we have 10 tries to guess it. Unfortunately, we a number is scanned, it stays in the terminal, so everyone can read and cheat.
I also tried to do something kinda dumb, which was use `printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n...")` with 29, but that way the code goes down and looks bad.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Turn off echo in the terminal so the characters are never printed.

Comment: Or, instead of `\n`, use `\r` and write spaces.

Comment: Or use terminal control sequences to clear the line.

Comment: TIAGO CAMEIRINHA, No general C answer.  Solution are terminal/OS specific.  What OS and compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the platform (OS).
In General there are several methods:

- Supressing echo via stty(): See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67709009/6607497
- Using  getpass() (obsolete)
- Use terminal escape sequences (like ANSI) to Query the input at a specific line, then erase that line.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code for details.
- Learn to use curses. See [http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/UnixAndC/CLanguage/Curses.pdf](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Ematloff/UnixAndC/CLanguage/Curses.pdf) for details
- [How to disable echo in windows console?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9217908/6607497)
- [ANSI C No-echo keyboard input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/558009/6607497)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/64524q/turning_off_echo_in_terminal_using_c/
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14220ac4-a557-4cea-b29d-f46222a36ef5/how-to-not-echo-the-input-of-consoleread
- http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/3570/
- https://falsinsoft.blogspot.com/2014/05/disable-terminal-echo-in-linux.html
- ...

Maybe you should have searched elsewhere first!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest thing (but certainly not the best)you can do is shell out to `stty` to manipulate the terminal database.  Eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
        char b[32];
        printf("prompt: ");
        system("stty -echo");  /* Turn off echo */
        if( scanf("%31s", b) == 1 ){
                printf("\nyou entered %s\n", b);
        }
        system("stty echo");   /* Turn echo back on */
        return 0;
}
```

Note that this does not handle signals well, and your terminal may end up with a modified state.

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows, you can specifies the maximum number of commands in the history buffer.:

```
system("doskey /listsize = 0");
```

In addition, You can simulate the keyboard shortcut ALT+F7 to clear the history.

[See more for windows.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/doskey)

If you use Unix, you can clean the history:

```
system("history -c");
```

Comment: Oh, I would be very angry if some program deletes my shell history!

Answer (score 0):

if you #include <stdlib.h>, system("cls"); should clear the terminal after the number is entered. I tried the game, its fun!