# how do I use read system call to take password interactively

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, passwords, go

how do I implement the following command line using system calls in golang?

```
read -s -p "Enter Password: " mypassword
```

that is, what additional options to set while reading the password to avoid the input to be echoed and force the input to be provided only interactively.

thanks.

Comment: In C I'd use `getpass()`. I don't know if that helps, but [getpass golang](http://www.google.com/search?q=getpass+golang) gets a few nice-looking google hits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getpasswd functionality in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137357/getpasswd-functionality-in-go)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `terminal.ReadPassword()` from package `terminal`.

```
func ReadPassword(fd int) ([]byte, error)
```

`ReadPassword` reads a line of input from a terminal without local echo. This is commonly used for inputting passwords and other sensitive data. The slice returned does not include the \n.

Package terminal provides support functions for dealing with terminals, as commonly found on UNIX systems.

More on it:

- http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/ssh/terminal

Answer (score -2):

You may use expect command for password interactively :

`expect "Enter Password:" {`

`send -- "$PASSWORD_VALUE\r"`

*e.g - while using sftp use below script*

sh expect.sh

`PASSWORD_VALUE="password"`

`spawn -noecho sftp username@ip`

`expect "Enter Password:" {`

`send -- "$PASSWORD_VALUE\r"`

#

Comment: That is completely wrong! I don't make -1, but please consider, that your answer has nothing to do with the question

Comment: Sincerely Apologies as not seen you are expected answer in golang. I had given answer as though process of linux commands. hope you get the answer. thanks