# Writing a CLI: How to avoid showing the typed password on screen

Tags: go, command-line-interface

I'm writing a command line tool with Go and one of the command will query the user for its username and password (and save it to a config file inside the home directory).

For now I couldn't realize how to replace the typed password to '*' or even not to type anything as a lot of command line tools are doing.

How does can this be done when using golang?

Answer (score 0):

Type this stuff into Google before you come here.

> you can do this by execing `stty -echo` to turn off echo and then 
>   `stty echo` after reading in the password to turn it back on

OR

> Just saw a mail in #go-nuts maillist. There is someone who wrote quite
>   a simple go package to be used. You can find it here:
>   https://github.com/howeyc/gopass
>
> It something like that:
>
> ```
> package main
>
> import "fmt" import "github.com/howeyc/gopass"
>
> func main() {
>     fmt.Printf("Password: ")
>     pass := gopass.GetPasswd()
>     // Do something with pass }
> ```

[Taken from another Stackoverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137357/getpasswd-functionality-in-go)

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find this question I guess because of poor title (:

Comment: It happens. Not a problem. Glad I could help! :)