# Replace echo input when entering a password

Tags: go, replace, passwords, echo, stdin

I'm trying to enter a password replacing the echo of the standard input by '*' using Golang. The default behavior of `func ReadPassword(fd int) ([]byte, error)` of package golang.org/x/term is to remove all the echo. But I want to create a more user-friendly interface so users can know that they are writing something.

So far the best solution has been [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71594131/13295504), which is pretty good, but when I delete a character from the input, the number of '*' does not decrease.

So I was wondering if there is any native way of replacing the echo of the standard input without losing the real input.

Thank you!