# golang simple server with interactive prompt

Tags: go, terminal, interactive

I am trying to build a simple CLI interface for my go process, I need to listen and serve on TCP port and get stats when connected to the port on TCP . I came across 'terminal' package to help with Password prompt, command history and other things. I tried to write up some code to achieve this. Although my client is not receiving any prompt or server is stuck on 'ReadLine' method. Any helpers?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal"
    "io"
    "net"
    _ "time"
)

func handleConnection(conn net.Conn) error {
    fmt.Println("Handling new connection...")
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("Closing connection...")
        conn.Close()
    }()
    r := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    w := bufio.NewWriter(conn)
    rw := bufio.NewReadWriter(r, w)
    term := terminal.NewTerminal(rw, "")
    term.SetPrompt(string(term.Escape.Red) + "> " + string(term.Escape.Reset))
    rePrefix := string(term.Escape.Cyan) + "Human says:" + string(term.Escape.Reset)
    line := "welcome"
    fmt.Fprintln(term, rePrefix, line)
    for {
        line, err := term.ReadLine()
        if err == io.EOF {
            return nil
        }
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if line == "" {
            continue
        }
        fmt.Fprintln(term, rePrefix, line)
    }
}

func main() {
    // Start listening to port 8888 for TCP connection
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8888")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    defer func() {
        listener.Close()
        fmt.Println("Listener closed")
    }()

    for {
        // Get net.TCPConn object
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            break
        }

        go handleConnection(conn)
    }
}
```

Comment: The server has a buffered writer, so remember to call Flush when you want to send the contents of the buffer to the underlying network connection. Eg, add `w.Flush()` after each `fmt.Fprintln(term, rePrefix, line)`.

Comment: Thanks ! this fixes one problem and now client is getting what server sends, although Readline is still stuck after sending data from client.

Comment: Sorry, could you please confirm whether you added *two* Flush calls to the server? One after the write before the loop, and one after the write inside the loop?

Comment: Yes that's right, problem is at 'term.ReadLine()' which is not unblocked after client sending data.

Comment: I can run your server locally and connect to it via `telnet localhost 8888`. With Flush calls it appears to work as intended: each line sent by telnet is echoed back from the server. It's not stuck on the ReadLine method. So perhaps check your client is sending correctly. If it's a go client, perhaps it's the same issue, a buffered writer not flushing.

Comment: @Mark thanks a lot, I was using 'nc' before and it was causing ReadLine stuck. Thanks Again !

Comment: Ok good. Also you can use `nc -C ....` where the -C flag means _each line feed (LF) character from the
             input data is translated into CR+LF before being written to the
             socket._

Comment: Again, with this also behavior is weird, I am not getting prompt and input is not echoed until I hit enter then my input and the prompt is shown. I guess it's getting buffered and not displayed until I hit enter. Is there a way out to make it natural https://play.golang.org/p/bYt_muOICgp . Here 'good()' works well and 'bad()' has problem as described.