# input password to command in golang

Tags: go

I need to use lxd-p2c(https://github.com/lxc/lxd/tree/master/lxd-p2c) in golang code.

I try to pass password to the binary `lxd-p2c` built by the code above, which uses `term.ReadPassword(0)`(https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/lxd-p2c/utils.go#L166)  to read password in Linux.

I did some search on the internet and tried following code but they just did not work.

```golang
# 1
cmd := exec.Command(command, args...)
cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader(password)

# 2
cmd := exec.Command(command, args...)
stdin, _ := cmd.StdinPipe()
io.WriteString(stdin, password)
```

Similar but simple code to test: https://play.golang.org/p/l-9IP1mrhA (code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32768479/9265302)

build the binary and call it in go.

---

edit:

No workaround found and I removed `term.ReadPassword(0)` in the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the error in your playground displays `inappropriate ioctl for device`.

Searching for the error message I found this [thread](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19909), which notes that non-terminal input is not supported for `terminal.ReadPassword`. My guess is that passing Stdin input this way makes it pass the input with a character device instead of with the necessary terminal device like tty or any such, making the read fail. `lxd-p2c` can't read the password from such an input device.