# Regular Expression matching at least n of m groups

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

I was going to write a regular expression that would match only if a string contains at least n different classes of characters. I was going to use this to force my users to create strong passwords and wanted to check if the password contains at least 3 of the following:

- Characters
- Capital Characters
- Numbers
- Special Characters

Writing a regular expression that matches if all of those classes are present is trivial using lookaheads. However, I cannot wrap my head around the "at least 3" part. Is this even possible (in a nice, compact expression) or would I have to create a monster expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this will be more compact than listing each possible combination of 3 of the 4.  It utilizes negative lookahead to make sure that the entire string is not composed of only one or two of the character classes you listed:

```
(?!([a-zA-Z]*|[a-z\d]*|[^A-Z\d]*|[A-Z\d]*|[^a-z\d]*|[^a-zA-Z]*)$).*
```

In order, the groups here are:

- lower and/or upper
- lower and/or digits
- lower and/or special
- upper and/or digits
- upper and/or special
- digits and/or special

This regex will fail if the entire string (because of the `$` in the negative lookahead) contains only characters from any of the above groups.

Comment: I really like this approach. Didn't even think about inverting the logic. Thanks alot, very clever!

Comment: Isn't this expression allowing spaces?

Comment: It does, [it is not uncommon for passwords to allow spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632167/should-users-be-allowed-to-entered-a-password-with-a-space-at-the-beginning-or-e).  If you need a version that doesn't allow spaces, change the `.*` at the end to `\S*`.

Comment: In the same vein, changing the `*` at the end to `{8,}` would add the requirement, "must be at least 8 characters long", right?

Comment: +1, Very nice logic: instead of accepting four "complex" cases you're rejecting 6 "simple" cases. Neat.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write an expression for each possible combination of 3 of the 4 (four expressions in total), and then | the individual expressions together so that they pass if they fulfill at least one of the original expressions.

Comment: Which is 4 expressions each about 3/4 the length of your current regular expression, so your final result would be about 3 x the size of your current regular expression. Not too bad.

Comment: I hoped I didn't had to do that. I think its not clean, especially since I will have to rewrite the same classes over and over. Thank you though for your clarification.

Comment: Why is not clean? create a method that does it and re-use it. It's much better than having one gigantic unreadable RegEx.

Comment: It will be one gigantic unreadable RegEx. And I am stuck to a single regular expression. I cannot split up anything in methods or several function calls. The interface to my client input validation mechanism is a single regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this solution?

```
var str='23khkS_s';

var countGroups=0;
if(str.match(/[a-z]+/))
    countGroups++;
if(str.match(/[A-Z]+/))
    countGroups++;
if(str.match(/[0-9]+/))
    countGroups++;
if(str.match(/[-_!@#$%*\(\)]+/))
    countGroups++;

console.log(countGroups);
```

Instead of using 1 monster-like expression you can use 4 small RE. And then work with variable `countGroups`, which contains number of maеched character groups.
I hope it is helpfull

Comment: This would be good if he controlled the entire solution end to end, but I suspect all he can do is put a regex into a text field for configuration.